# Update user's details and display back the same

Tags: php, html, mysql

So i have the following code snippet which updates the user's profile.

```
<?php 
    // FETCH THE DATA FIRST FROM DB
    $fetch_profile_data = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `useremail` = :user_email";
    $exec_profile_data = $DB->prepare($fetch_profile_data);
    $exec_profile_data->bindValue(":user_email", $_SESSION['user_email'] );
    $exec_profile_data->execute();
    $user_profile_data = $exec_profile_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    

    $base_upload_folder = "./uploads";
    $actual_user_avatar = $_FILES['myprofilepic']["name"];
    $base_target_file = $base_upload_folder.basename($_FILES['myprofilepic']["name"]);
    $user_avatar_extension = pathinfo($base_target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $user_avatar_size = $_FILES['myprofilepic']['size'];
    $maxsize    = 4097152;
    // set the allowed file types
    $avatar_allowed_array =  array('jpeg','jpg','png');

    // PROCESS THE FORM IF SUBMIT IS SET
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
       $bio = $_POST['userbio'];
       $url = $_POST['mysite'];
       
       if ( !empty( $bio ) || !empty( $url ) || !empty( $actual_user_avatar ) ){
          $update_user_bio = "UPDATE `users` SET userbio = :user_bio, userwebsite = :user_site, profilepicture = :user_picture WHERE useremail = :user_email";
       try {
          $execute_update_bio = $DB->prepare($update_user_bio);
          $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_bio", $bio);
          $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_site", $url);
          $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_picture", $actual_user_avatar);
          $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_email", $_SESSION['user_email']);
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myprofilepic"]["tmp_name"], $base_target_file)
          $execute_update_bio->execute();
      } catch (Exception $ex) {
          echo $ex->getMessage();
      }
       }
    }
?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Username: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_profile_data['username']; ?>" disabled="true">
  Email: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_profile_data['useremail']; ?>" disabled="true">
  BIO: <textarea name="mybio" id="mybio"><?php echo $user_profile_data['userbio']; ?></textarea>
  URL: <input type="url" name="mysite" id="mysite" value="<?php echo $user_profile_data['userwebsite']; ?>">
  PICTURE: <input type="file" name="myprofilepic" id="myprofilepic">
  <img src="./uploads/<?php echo $user_profile_data['profilepicture']; ?>">
  <button name="submit" id="submit">Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

So basically i want the user to be able to edit his profile, once he has edited it display back the same. But the main idea here is check if each individual value exists and then update.
For example:

- If only the textarea value is changed update only the relevant column and display back the same value and vice versa.
- If the URL field/Image file is not change or empty do not update it.

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: rearrange the code the , the code for update data should be on top and then after that the select query and assign of variables to display should be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : i have just rearrange the code

```
<?php 


 $base_upload_folder = "./uploads";
    $actual_user_avatar = $_FILES['myprofilepic']["name"];
    $base_target_file = $base_upload_folder.basename($_FILES['myprofilepic']["name"]);
    $user_avatar_extension = pathinfo($base_target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $user_avatar_size = $_FILES['myprofilepic']['size'];
    $maxsize    = 4097152;
    // set the allowed file types
    $avatar_allowed_array =  array('jpeg','jpg','png');
// PROCESS THE FORM IF SUBMIT IS SET
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
   $bio = $_POST['userbio'];
   $url = $_POST['mysite'];
   
   if ( !empty( $bio ) || !empty( $url ) || !empty( $actual_user_avatar ) ){
      $update_user_bio = "UPDATE `users` SET userbio = :user_bio, userwebsite = :user_site, profilepicture = :user_picture WHERE useremail = :user_email";
   try {
      $execute_update_bio = $DB->prepare($update_user_bio);
      $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_bio", $bio);
      $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_site", $url);
      $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_picture", $actual_user_avatar);
      $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_email", $_SESSION['user_email']);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myprofilepic"]["tmp_name"], $base_target_file)
      $execute_update_bio->execute();
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
   }
}

// FETCH THE DATA FIRST FROM DB
$fetch_profile_data = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `useremail` = :user_email";
$exec_profile_data = $DB->prepare($fetch_profile_data);
$exec_profile_data->bindValue(":user_email", $_SESSION['user_email'] );
$exec_profile_data->execute();
$user_profile_data = $exec_profile_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Username: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_profile_data['username']; ?>" disabled="true">
  Email: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_profile_data['useremail']; ?>" disabled="true">
  BIO: <textarea name="mybio" id="mybio"><?php echo $user_profile_data['userbio']; ?></textarea>
  URL: <input type="url" name="mysite" id="mysite" value="<?php echo $user_profile_data['userwebsite']; ?>">
  PICTURE: <input type="file" name="myprofilepic" id="myprofilepic">
  <img src="./uploads/<?php echo $user_profile_data['profilepicture']; ?>">
  <button name="submit" id="submit">Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try {
      $DB->beginTransaction();

      $execute_update_bio = $DB->prepare($update_user_bio);
      $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_bio", $bio);
      $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_site", $url);
      $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_picture", $actual_user_avatar);
      $execute_update_bio->bindValues(":user_email", $_SESSION['user_email']);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myprofilepic"]["tmp_name"], $base_target_file)
      $execute_update_bio->execute();
      $DB->commit();
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
       $DB->rollBack();
      echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
```

if you have an error, the update data will not save ...

source https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php